# Browser Setting Content Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring

I created an annotation for each @PostMapping citing @CrossOrigin(origin = “*”). At the beginning I was running into a 415 error, I’m now running into a 503 error and the content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded still remains. As you can see, I may have compounded the issue. I’m trying to change the content type to application/json.

I’ve tried programmatically changing the content type, nothing was working. I went from a 415 error to a 503 error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey @LinFelix unfortunately I can’t for obvious reasons.

Comment: What reasons? None are obvious to me

Answer (score 0):

I believe 503 status code means your application failed to start because there is no "origin" member inside @CrossOrigin annotation.
Try with @CrossOrigin("`*`") or @CrossOrigin(origins="`*`")

You could read here the docs for @CrossOrigin annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html

Comment: Hey there @George Vilau, thank you for your response and assistance. As mentioned in my original post, I’ve already cited @CrossOrigin(origins="*"). Would you happen to have any other suggestions? I’ve already tried programmatically setting the content type to application/json, and they’ve all failed. I think the browser is the culprit.